# How to Restore database automatically and periodically without Jobs?

Tags: sql-server, restore, jobs, database-restore, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am allowing guest users to log onto my database and so I want to restore the database once a week to wipe it of the quest users details, etc.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. This version does not have Jobs.

Is it possible to automatically resotre the database without the use of a job?

Comment: Well my friend any command cannot trigger itself, We will need a job or scheduler to do this triggering work so that the script is executed and your task is completed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Windows Scheduled task, which executes [`sqlcmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and makes the necessary `RESTORE DATABASE` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use Batch File

Write the `sequel Command` Which will Execute the restore operation Using `batch file`

Then Using `Task scheduler` trigger automatically that `batch file` to run whenever neccesery.